# CXF on WebSphere 6.1 Class Loading Problem

Tags: java, websphere, classloader, cxf

I have a project with the following configuration:

- WebSphere Application Server 6.1.0.19
- **wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar** at the `$WAS_ROOT/java/jre/lib/ext` directory, (to overwrite wsdl4j-1.6.1 included in WAS 6.1).
- **cxf-2.4.0.jar** (and others dependencies) at the `$WAS_ROOT/lib/ext` directory.
- An **EAR 'X'** with a **Web Module 'Y'**.
- The Web Module 'Y' has a **JAR Module 'Z'** (at the  `WEB-INF/lib` directory).
- 'Z' has a set of classes that implement a SOAP Web Service generated using CXF's wsdl2java.
- 'Y' has a business class (at the `WEB-INF/classes` directory) that calls the SOAP Web Service Client at 'Z'.

This configuration works well at my development enviroment (Rational Application Developer with a WebSphere AS 6.1 runtime). But at the QA enviroment, I had the following exception, (please pay attention at bolds in the stack trace):

`org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException

at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.loadInterface(Extension.java:134)

at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.loadAndRegister(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:160) 

at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeansOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:256) 

at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl.getExtension(CXFBusImpl.java:99)

at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.notifyLifecycleManager(ClientImpl.java:186)

at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.(ClientImpl.java:117)

at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.createClient(ClientFactoryBean.java:104)

at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:92)

at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:152)

at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)

at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:464)

at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:331)

at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:318)

at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:46)

at web.service.client.implementation.at.z.module.method(Unknown Source)

at business.class.at.y.web.module.method(AvisoCobroDAO.java:86)

... 32 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientLifeCycleManager

at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:472)

at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:373)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:561)

at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.loadInterface(Extension.java:132)

... 51 more`

Seems like the `CompoundClassLoader` (which works at application level) is trying to load a CXF's class which exists at the server runtime level.

**I hope somebody help me with this issue. I'll be very very grateful.**

Comment: Where is the ClientLifecycleManager class located?  Is it in cxf-2.4.0.jar?  Note that putting jars in WAS_HOME/lib/ext/ won't actually override WAS classes since jars in that directory are toward the end of the class path, and the WAS extension class loader uses "parent first" class loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing Jars in the WAS_HOME/lib/ext should be your last resort.

Always try the PARENT_LAST classloader mode and have your classes/jars picked up first.

This would avoid a number of problems for you.

The App Server start up would use this directory extensively and if there are clashes it  might not even start up.

THe best way to troubleshoot is to turn on classloading and look at the native_stdout/stderr file and see who is loading the class(es) that is in question.

Bkail,

Did you mean to say things differently? This path is high up the class  loader chain so it would be checked earlier (with the default PARENT_FIRST) class loading policy.

This would be in the second rung (after the BOOT CLassloader of the JDK) and it's extensions.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: @bkail, @Manglu, thanks for your response. @Manglu, you're right about placing the jars at `WAS_HOME/lib/ext` the fact is 'Z' Jar Module contains other business classes required for other proyects and I cannot to place it at a higher level because could have different versions among the different projects at the server. The good new is that this mourning, I enable the Class Loader Visor, restart the server and run the business rule and it works! Black Magic? I'll never know...